# how can i use Google Analytics's stats of my websites pages in my php script?

Tags: php, google-analytics

i have a question about google analytics. i created a php script and want to make a counter for this. my friend suggested me to use google analytics to have a nice counter. but for example, i want to show just "x.html" stats page in my website. can i do that or not?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the google analytics API in php.  You can use [the information on this site](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/google-analytics-api-and-php/)
to get you started.  Not sure what you are looking for from Analytics, but there are links to the API files and some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit [GAPI](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) to accomplish this job. Code examples are [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/display-google-analytics-stats-on-your.html).

Gory details: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/